# Event when WebGL crashes on page?

Tags: javascript, exception, three.js, webgl

I have an application which uses WebGL through the Three.js library. Sometimes the application crashes. Are there any event in plain javascript or in three.js for catching this.

Now I'm just listening on window.onerror event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help if your *browser* is crashing, but if the WebGL side is crashing, you should be able to capture that through the [`canvas.webglcontextlost`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/webglcontextlost) event. (More event info: https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost)

Three.js also listens for these events, but doesn't seem to do anything with them other than prevent `WebGLRenderer.render` from executing on a lost context.

Three.js *does not* block the propagation of the event, so you can also add your own listener, if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.